# "lend" vs. "borrow"

Tags: word-meaning

To me, *Borrowing* and *Lending* have the same meaning, but what is appropriate to use in the below sentence and why we should prefer that word?

> Thank you for __________ me your book.
>      Borrowing
>      Lending

Comment: A hint I always told people who struggled with this, and have told me it works, is to match it up to "buying" and "selling". You'd never say "Thank you for buying me your book." but you would say "Thank you for selling me your book."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Borrow* and *lend* have 'reciprocal' meanings. *Lend* is what the person who gives the book does, *borrow* is what the person who receives the book does.

(But both imply that the *borrower* will eventually return the book to the *lender*.)

It is ordinarily the borrower who thanks the lender.

ADDED:
As Hellion points out, *borrow* is used in some dialects to mean *lend*, but this is not permitted in Standard English (whatever that is). And I have never encountered *lend* with the sense *borrow*.

Comment: In "City Boy," by Herman Wouk, Herbie Bookbinder asks his (naked) chum "would you like to lend (borrow) half of my pajamas?" But that was a deliberate malapropism by an adolescent boy.

Comment: "Lend" being used to mean "borrow" was moderately common where I grew up (North East England). That was about 30 years ago - I don't know if it's still common now.

Comment: @NigelHarper That's fascinating. [ODO, s.v. *lend*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lend) under 'usage' confirms that this is still current.

Comment: although you give good explanation to the meaning of the words, you don't actually answer the question

Comment: @IvoBeckers It answers the question completely by defining both "borrow" and "lend" and saying that "It is ordinarily the borrower who thanks the lender."

Comment: @NigelHarper. As in: "Can I lend your bike please"? (Or probably more likely: "Give iz a lend of your bike will ya"?) It was still common about 10-15 years ago when I growing up. I still live in North East England, and don't hear it as much, but that might just be because I work and associate more with Southerners now.

Answer (score 11):

In some parts of the English-speaking world (including yours, apparently), *borrow* and *lend* have the same meaning.  In other parts (including mine), they are reciprocal to each other:

> I borrow a book = "I take a book temporarily"
>   I lend a book = "I give a book temporarily"

In those parts of the world, it is improper to say "borrow me X" or "borrow X to me", as the presence of the indirect object implies the opposite action from the verb; only "lend" works.

To my mind, it is preferable to use each word in one direction only for ease of understanding.

Comment: Where do they have the same meaning?  I've never come across that before.  It reminds me of the nonstandard use of *learn* meaning "teach", as in "I'll learn him a lesson!"

Comment: In northern Minnesota and other parts of the midwest (especially rural) I have heard "borrow me X" as a regular feature; on the east coast I never heard such a thing.  Personally I think it's sick and wrong to use them interchangeably like that, but I'm trying not to be prescriptivist about it.  :-)

Comment: Growing up in Alabama I occasionally heard "Can you borrow me the loan of" -!

Answer (score 2):

The correct word is lending, because is means the action of giving, while borrowing shows the action of taking. e.g. John borrowed Peter's book. Peter lent John his book.
Hope it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing and lending have **opposite** meanings that correspond to taking, and giving, respectively.

You, ARG, are the borrower (taker). The other party is the lender (giver). The borrower/taker thanks the lender/giver.

The difference between borrower and taker is that the borrower eventually **returns** (hopefully) the book. In which case the "lender" may say, "Thank you for returning the book."

But the borrower has been the receiver, and the lender has been the giver, of a "favor."

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about these specific forms of the two words? If so, then "lending" is the correct word, as "Thank you for borrowing me your book" isn't grammatically correct.

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs: no, "Thank you for borrowing me your book" *isn't* grammatically **INcorrect**; i.e., it is grammatically correct. As is "Would you please hand me that piano?" As is ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) They are merely *semantically* nonsensical.

Comment: @Scott Grammar matters here too.  *Borrow* doesn't appear ditransitively in Standard English.  When a head is given complements it doesn't license, we have a grammar problem.